# How to take 'snapshot' of variable value before a for loop? C#

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        float  myfloat = rnd.Next(1, 50);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            myfloat = 3;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(myfloat);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Say I want to change the value of a variable for the duration of a for loop, but then I want it to go back to whatever it was just befoe the loop (if i don't know what that value was). How would I do something like that?

With this code 'myfloat' is stuck at 3 after the loop ends.

Comment: If you want it to revert to it's previous value after the loop, why not leave that variable and create a second one that the loop can change?

Comment: Create a new `float` variable, such as `float oldValue = myfloat;` and after the loop assign it back to `myfloat`

Comment: Why not just create a  new variable inside the loop and leave `myfloat` untouched?. If that doesn't fit your use case show a more sensible example of what you are trying to do

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recommend using a "temporary" variable.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    float  myfloat = rnd.Next(1, 50);
    float  tempFloat = myfloat;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        myfloat = 3;
    }

    myfloat = tempFloat;
    Console.WriteLine(myfloat);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

It could look something like this.